# How to override private var in superclass

Tags: swift, class, subclass, private, superclass

So I have the following superclass:

```
class Vehicle {

    private var _maxSpeed: Int = 100

    var maxSpeed: Int {
        get {
            return _maxSpeed
        }

var tooFast: Bool {
        get {
            if maxSpeed >= 140 {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Plus I have some subclasses in which I want to override maxSpeed... per example:

```
class SuperCar: Vehicle {
//override the maxspeed...

}
```

But how should I approach this? Or is this only possible if we don't make it private? I tried to throw the private part out of the window but that won't work as well...

```
class Vehicle {

    var maxSpeed: Int = 100

var tooFast: Bool {
        get {
            if maxSpeed >= 140 {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}

class SuperCar: Vehicle {
// override the maxSpeed...
override var maxSpeed: Int = 200
// Will not work...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your private member variables in the init method

```
class Vehicle{
    private var maxSpeed: Int
    init(maxSpeed: Int = 100){
        self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
    }
}

class SuperCar: Vehicle {
    override init(maxSpeed: Int = 200){
        super.init(maxSpeed: maxSpeed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just put the class and subclass in the same file. `private` has nothing to do with inheritance. It has to do with file scope. Anything in the same file has access to `private` members.

That said, you almost certainly shouldn't be using inheritance here. `Vehicle` should almost certainly be a protocol. Then you wouldn't have any of the headaches of inheritance or `private`.

```
protocol Vehicle {
    var maxSpeed: Int {get}
}

extension Vehicle {
    // Default implementation if none is given
    var maxSpeed: Int { return 100 }

    // Another method that applies to all Vehicles
    var tooFast: Bool {
        return maxSpeed < 140 // (feels like this should be >= 140, but matching your code)
    }
}

struct SuperCar: Vehicle {
    // override the default implementation for the protcocol
    var maxSpeed = 200
}
```

Comment: If the original class is in a 3rd-party framework, we can't put subclasses in the same file

Answer (score 0):

For a Swift 3 version of Rob's answer, you can't override private, but interestingly you can with **fileprivate** computed properties. You have to put the class in the same file though.

I did this today:

```
protocol Renderer {
}

class BaseClass {
     private let _renderer: Renderer = BaseClassRenderer()
     fileprivate var renderer: Renderer {
         return _renderer
     }
}

class Subclass: BaseClass {
     private let _renderer: Renderer = SubclassRenderer()
     override fileprivate var renderer: Renderer {
         return _renderer
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can override computed property

```
class C {
    var a: Int { return 10 }
}
class D:C {
    override var a: Int  { return 100 }
```

Comment: and? The question was about private property

Comment: @Gargo :-) check the question, especially  " ... I have some subclasses in which I want to override maxSpeed...", and check others answers too to see the context.

Comment: Reread the question... 1)"is this only possible if we don't make it private?"; 2)I too frequently encounter the same problem. A lot of beginners read books about OOP see "private modifier is cool" and then spam github with their poor-quality code. And if you face with problems you can't simply fix it because almost all the code is marked "private". In the same time there is no explanation in your answer about private/public modifiers - you just post a chunk of code which is not related to the question

Comment: @Gargo do you have an idea why do you need to override private computed property? Do you think, that accepted answer is better? From my point of view even Rob's answer is not too much better. My point of view was "do it the simplest way!" don't try to reevaluate the gear.